# How do I remove certain elements matching criteria from an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array.

```
const arr = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'orange', 'peach'];
```

The test function is like this.

```
function test(str) {
  return str.length >= 6;
}
```

I can find the elements easily with `filter` method. But I want to remove these elements from the array.

The result should be

```
['apple', 'pear', 'peach']
```

Comment: What relation does your current function have to the one which you actually have in mind?

Comment: you could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with your function. btw, there you need only to return the condition `return str.length >= 6;`.

Comment: `arr.includes(['apple', 'pear', 'peach'])`? This returns `true` or `false` if items are found in the array.

Comment: @Red No it doesn't. It just throws an error since there is no `inArray` method.

Comment: @Aplet123 sorry, I meant includes ;)

Comment: If you can find them, then you can also "not" find them. So, where's the problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because my question is wrong

Comment: The question and output are not matching. You want `strings` bigger or equal then `>= 6` but the output shows `string` smaller then ` <= 6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the given [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) approach

```
array.filter(string => !test(string))
```

you could take the advantage of a functional approach which takes a function and retuns the negated result of it.

```js
function test(str) {
    return str.length >= 6;
}

function not(fn) {
    return (...args) => !fn(...args);
}

const
    array = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'orange', 'peach'],
    result = array.filter(not(test));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a function just for this, [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const arr = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'orange', 'peach'];
function test(str) {
    return str.length >= 6;
}

// we need to negate the result since we want to keep elements where test returns false
console.log(arr.filter(x => !test(x)));
// logs: ['apple', 'pear', 'peach']
```